# issues with PowerShell query

Tags: powershell, t-sql, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using the Invoke-Sqlcmd command in PowerShell to execute a query so I can force the correct encoding (UTF8) as well as the removal of the headers and other characters from the results. This approach is giving me 99% of what I need, only issue I'm having is the extra insertion of a space after each column. The code below is what I've thrown together to force the removal of CR, LF and commas.

How can I keep everything past the Select-Object? If I remove the ConvertTo-Csv which caontains the -Delimiter I'm assuming is responsible for the extra space if fails, if I set the -Delimiter to no space I get "Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."

If I'm not trying to export to CSV how can I remove since it doesn't seem to be needed?

```
| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter " " | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | % {$_ -replace '\n'," "} | % {$_ -replace '\r'," "}|Out-File ("\\WINSVR2019-DELTA\Ggp\customer.txt") -Force -Encoding ascii
```

How can I keep everything past the Select-Object? If I remove the ConvertTo-Csv which caontains the -Delimiter I'm assuming is responsible for the extra space if fails, if I set the -Delimiter to no space I get:

> Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'. Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long.

Below are the query results. I have to force each field to a certain character value, which is why the delimiter is causing an issue. The Pipe is a visual indicator where the delimiter is that I'm trying to remove. Again, this is exactly what I need, minus the delimiter.

005688             |Brothers Electric Supply                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |PO Box 8699                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |Riverside                                       |UT                                               |35807              |US|20000              |06152022|           14904.00|0.00000            |0                  |REI

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on the exact requirements, and I suspect that an OO solution based on the [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow) objects that [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) outputs may be preferable, but to address your question as asked:

- Indeed, [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Csv) and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv) require that the `-Delimiter` argument be *a single, literal character*.
- A *workaround* if you want *no* delimiter is to choose a temporary delimiter (separator) that you know not be part of the data itself, and to remove all instances of it later.

Applied to your code, using `` "`t" ``, i.e. a tab character as the temporary delimiter:

```bash
... | 
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" | 
  Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
  % { $_ -replace "`t`"", '' -replace '[\r\n]', " " } |
  Out-File -Force -Encoding ascii \\WINSVR2019-DELTA\Ggp\customer.txt
```

Note:

- As in your own attempt, the streamlined `-replace` operation replaces a CR (`\r`) and a LF (`\n`) *each* with a space. If your intent is to instead replace each CRLF *sequence* with a space, use `'\r\n'`. (In general, if you want to match both Windows-format CRLF sequences and Unix-format LF-only newlines, use `'\r?\n'`)